# Knockout.js - How to change the viewmodel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm trying to change the view model which is bound to some part of a DOM template (instead of changing the values of the view model) but I just can't figure out how or if it's even possible

Here's the scenario:

- Create a new View Model object
- Bind it (e.g. applyBindings(myViewModel)
- Create another View Model object
- Bind the new object to the same part of the DOM so all elements are now bound to the new object.

I want to do the equivalent of changing the value of DataContext of a control in WPF (on which KO's MVVM pattern is based)

The reason for this is that I'm trying to use the same view model for both the representation of the object in a list and the representation of the object in its own view, so I already have a view model for all objects being shown in the list.

There are other workarounds but I think this would be the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: Can you show your js code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/e29EZ/1/ open the js console to see that the callback is executed twice. This other fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e29EZ/6/ is using cleanNode (thanks to nathan gonzález below) but it's still executing the callback twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two way of working with multiple viewmodel. The first way is to do multiple binding like @nathan gonzalez said. You should do binding up your viewmodels. However this complicates things a bit. Therefore difficult to manage.

The second way is to use master viewmodel. I would recommend this.

http://jsfiddle.net/sinanakyazici/e29EZ/10/

```
<div data-bind="with: mainvm">
    <span data-bind="text: prop, click : action"></span>
</div>

var vm = function(value)
{
    this.prop = ko.observable(value);
    var self = this;
    this.action = function() {
        console.log("clicked: " + self.prop());
    }
}

var master = {
    mainvm : ko.observable(null)
}

master.mainvm(new vm('viewmodel 1'));
master.mainvm(new vm('viewmodel 2'));
ko.applyBindings(master);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! For the record, here's the post (thanks to nathan gonzalez) where Michael Best, a KO collaborator, states that this is possible: github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/41

Answer (score 1):

so `ko.applyBindings()` should cover this for you.  you can pass in a 2nd parameter that tells  which top level element to apply the bindings to, like so:

```
 ko.applyBindings(myExistingViewModel, $('#someElementId')[0]);
```

you may want to clean the elements first though, like this:

```
ko.cleanNode($('#someElementId')[0]);
```

this completely removes the bindings and clears the in memory data for that element and its children bindings.

Comment: Thanks. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e29EZ/6/, even though I called cleanNode, the click callback is executed twice (check the js console). Also, is cleanNode documented somewhere?

Comment: ok, hmm.  i found this (https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/41) talking about a lack of support for what you are doing.  have you thought about putting your html into a template and creating the dom structure brand new every from the template?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although Steve Sanderson states that it's not a supported feature (~2 years ago). Michael Best who is an important knockout collaborator later (~11 months ago) explains how to do it using observable viewmodels as @sinanakyazici posted.

Comment: @JuanCampa, yeah, didn't make it that far down?  did that work for you?  if so, post the solution and accept it as the answer.  posterity and all that.

Comment: Done! @sinanakyazici's answer is the one